# Repeated data in android spinner

Tags: android, list, adapter, android-spinner

I'm attempting to populate a spinner with all installed applications except system apps. I'm running into two problems:

1) I am getting **repeated** data

2) When my spinner is populated and I open the list of spinner items and there can sometimes be **gaps** in between the app names.

See my adapter code below:

```
public class PackageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

private List<ApplicationInfo> applications;
private Context context;
private PackageManager packageManager = null;

public PackageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    // setting up the List applications with all the list of installed apps
    applications = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    try {
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager != null) {
            applications = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return applications.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return applications.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return applications.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View spinView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // setting up the view
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        spinView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spin_layout, null);
    } else {
        spinView = convertView;
    }

    // getting one application from the list of apps.
    final ApplicationInfo application = this.applications.get(position);

    // filtering out the system apps and getting the application name
    String appName = "";
    if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(application.packageName) != null) {
        appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(application).toString();
    }
    TextView t1 = (TextView) spinView.findViewById(R.id.field1);

    if (!appName.equals("")) {
        t1.setText(appName);
    }

    return spinView;
   }
}
```

Any help on either of the above two would be greatly appreciated! TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code, i have build and tested below code, you can also replace your code to this one,

this will give you **Installed package, Source dir** of all applications in device, will display all package in spinner

```
public class PackageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

private List<String> applications = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
private String TAG = "PackageAdapter";
PackageManager pm;

public PackageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    pm = context.getPackageManager();
    // setting up the List applications with all the list of installed apps
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

        if(!isSystemPackage(packageInfo)){
            Log.i(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
            Log.i(TAG, "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
            applications.add(packageInfo.packageName);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return applications.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return applications.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return applications.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View spinView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // setting up the view
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        spinView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spin_layout, null);
    } else {
        spinView = convertView;
    }

    TextView t1 = (TextView) spinView.findViewById(R.id.field1);

    String packageNames = applications.get(position);
    if (packageNames != null && !packageNames.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

        String appName = "";
        try {
            appName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(applications.get(position), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        t1.setText(appName);
    }

    return spinView;
}


private boolean isSystemPackage(ApplicationInfo applicationInfo) {
    return ((applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Amit Vaghela Ty for your post & help with this! So I've just replaced my adapter code with yours and my spinner is now showing all package names not the application name, also my spinner is being populated with system apps. My spinner items must be displayed as app name as user probably won't know the package name of app and we also cannot allow the user to select system apps from this list. Any ideas how we could go about amending the code to suit this?

Comment: check my updated answer. your problem is solved@DavidJarvis

Comment: @Amint Vaghela Great!! ty